# add business days to a date field in access 2010

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a Date Ordered field that shows on a report and I want that date to appear red if it is more than 3 business days old. I have seen a couple different codes but they are lengthy and I am not sure how to apply them to my report or even in the query. I believe my database has Sunday as the first day of the week. Would love to understand this as I have other reports I would like to apply this too. I have no formal training in access. Your help is GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no short or obtuse code for this, indeed not if holidays should be taken into account.

One example is my function here: [DateDiffWorkdays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56630108/why-does-my-calcworkingdays-vba-function-give-me-two-different-results-on-the-sa/56631139#56631139).

However, all you need is to copy-paste the full code into a new module, compile, and save.

Then, to check, use an expression similar to this in the *Format* event of the *Details* section of the report:

```vb
Private Sub Detailsection_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)

    Me!YourTextbox.ForeColor = IIf(DateDiffWorkdays([OrderDate],Date()) > 3, vbRed, vbBlack)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. When I try to open the report now it gives me this message: This calculated column contains an invalid expressoin. I don't need the holidays to be counted for just the weekends. So the link to your datediffworkdays, not sure which part of that you recommend copy and paste. Thanks again for your help

Comment: You ned all of it.

Comment: Can't tell, It is as simple to use as _DateDiff_.