# Calculating the holidays of employees without counting the weekends

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using `Microsoft Access` to calculate the number of holidays of doctors. Doctors have up to 31 days for holidays per year from where I extract the count of holidays.

However I don't want to count the weekends between start and end days.

Currently my code is the following, which counts the weekends:

```
TRANSFORM 31-Nz(Sum(DateDiff("d",DateAdd("d",-1,leaves.leave_starting_date),leaves.leave_end_date)),0) AS Days
SELECT doctors.Name
FROM doctors LEFT JOIN leaves ON doctors.ID = leaves.doctor_id
GROUP BY doctors.Name
PIVOT Year(leaves.leave_starting_date);
```

Any help?

Comment: what about public holidays?

Comment: @CaiusJard Currently no.

Answer (score 1):

Replace *DateDiff* with a function that excludes weekends (and, optionally, public holidays as well) from the difference in calendar days.

An example is my function **DateDiffWorkdays** posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56631139/3527297).