# SQL Day Count Calculation between two dates using two tables T1 = Days, T2 = Week Ending Date

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wza9T.jpg)
I would like to create a query that takes the Week Ending Date (typically a Friday) and calculate the number of Working Days in each Week.

I have a choice of either every day possible (All Days), or just the Working Days.  For example, some weeks would be shorter than other due to designated Holidays.  I coded each day as either 1 = Working Day, 2 = Sat or Sunday and 3 = Holiday.

Which would be the easier solution?  Go exclusively the Working Days off the Working Days Qry against the Week Ending Table?  Or use the All Days Qry against the Week Ending Table?  Tried looking up as much as possible on this very helpful site, but couldn't quite find a match to this.  Thanks

Tried looking up a lot here, but couldn't find an exact match to my problem.  Mainly a Design View guy here, with limited SQL experience.

Comment: Not enough information to help. What queries are being used? What database do you have? (as the information hovering the `sql` tag says to add _the_ related DB tag that you actually use, no spam tagging please.)

Comment: This is Access 2007.  The query for the exclusive working days, simply sorts a 21 year full calendar from 2015 through 2036.  Every day is there and is split up into three categories, Work Day, Off Day and Holiday.  I want to be be able to roll up the number of days, for each week ending and count the days.  Some companies have work  days 4/10's, some 5/40's.  Add the Holidays and you might have only three days in a work week, or four, if you're on a 5/40.  Or even two, if it's the beginning of the year.  Late here and thank you for your help.  The picture shows the data.

Comment: Qry 1 Columns: Year, MoNameShort, Formal Date, DayCd, Day Hours.  Tbl_2: Year, Month Name, DayName, Week Ending Date.

Answer (score 0):

> Which would be the easier solution?

I'm not sure, but a simpler method could be to record the holidays separately, and then calculate the difference in workdays between any two dates.

For this, you can use my function [DateDiffWorkdays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56631139/3527297).

For extended date handling and calculation, see my library at **GitHub**: [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date).

Comment: Thank You, I will look into that.  I really can't exclude the Holidays, as I'm developing a program that can be used by different companies or entities that recognize some holidays and not others.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: Sure, record the holidays in the holiday table.

Comment: That will be the eventual plan, Gustav, to allow the Holidays in a separate table.  This is the bare bones database to start.